# Creating a simple while loop

Tags: python, input, while-loop

How can I create a while loop that asks a user a fruit and if the fruit is 5 or less characters print i like (the fruit) otherwise print i do not like (the fruit), and when Stop is entered the program stops.

```
user_input = input("Enter a fruit ")

while user_input != "Stop":
  if user_input == "Stop":
    print("Goodbye")

  elif len(user_input) <= 5: 
    print("I like ", user_input)

  elif len(user_input) > 5: 
    print("I do not like ", user_input)
```

This is what I tried but the loop is continuous and does not stop until it times out. How can I easily fix this with the code I have already written?

Comment: You don't give a way for the user to enter another input.

Answer (score 2):

You never modify `input` inside the loop.

Either add another `input()` call at the end of the loop, or use an infinite loop with `input()` as the first statement in the loop:

```
# Infinite loop
while True:
    user_input = input("Enter a fruit (or Stop to end): ")

    if user_input == "Stop":
        print("Goodbye")
        # Break out of the loop
        break

    elif len(user_input) <= 5: 
        print("I like ", user_input)

    elif len(user_input) > 5: 
        print("I do not like ", user_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need ask the user again at the end of the while loop to update the user_input variable, otherwise it will not be updated**

user_input = input("Enter a fruit ")

while user_input != "Stop":

if user_input == "Stop":
print("Goodbye")

elif len(user_input) <= 5:
print("I like ", user_input)

elif len(user_input) > 5:
print("I do not like ", user_input)

user_input = input("Enter a fruit ")

Answer (score 0):

Usually with a repetitive loop situation like this, usually you want to use a "while True:" scenario and then utilize a "break" statement to exit the "while" loop.  Following is a snippet of code you might analyze.

```
while True:

    user_input = input("Enter a fruit ")

    if user_input == "Stop":
        print("Goodbye")
        break
        
    elif len(user_input) <= 5:
        print("I like", user_input)
        
    else:
        print("I do not like", user_input)
```

This provides a graceful exit after allowing the user to enter an indeterminant number of fruits.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/Fruit$ python3 Fruit.py 
Enter a fruit apple
I like apple
Enter a fruit pear
I like pear
Enter a fruit grapes
I do not like grapes
Enter a fruit Stop
Goodbye
```

Give that a try.